# Facebook App Center error: Misconfigured App

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've got a not-yet-released iOS app that's also supposed to have a Facebook App Center page. The Facebook App Center page is all set up and **works fine when being previewed**. But if I try to access the page directly (i.e. through `www.facebook.com/appcenter/myappname`), I'm getting the following error:

> Misconfigured App Sorry, the details for MyAppName cannot be displayed
>   because the app is misconfigured.

My guess is that I'm seeing this since I haven't submitted the app details page ("App Detail Page Status: Unsubmitted"), but I want to verify that this is the case before we go live. Otherwise, people might end up on this broken page, while we have to figure out what the issue is.

I've obviously tried Googling for this issue and looking through the Facebook docs, but failed to find any answer.

Could someone **please confirm that this will work fine** once I've submitted the app detail page?

*I've set up other App Center pages before and it's worked fine, but in those cases I've been able to submit the app detail page right away.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behaviour, hence why you have a Preview function to see what the page would look like. You will have to submit the app to the App Center for the App Center URL to work correctly.